# PHPUnit : Fatal error handling

Tags: php, error-handling, phpunit, fatal-error

I use PHPUnit for unit tests, but when a **fatal error** is triggered, the script **dies** and I have no correct PHPUnit output.

I'd like that the PHPUnit output stays **correctly formated**, because it is read by a plugin for Eclipse. Actually the fatal error stops PHPUnit and in Eclipse the plugin can't interpret anything (because the PHPUnit script **had** an error, instead of handling it).

Thanks

Comment: what sort of fatal errors? if they're syntax or semantics-related, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to use PHPUnit's process isolation features - start each test suite in a new process.

```
phpunit --process-isolation ...
```

This is the only way to make sure fatal errors don't break your phpunit output.

## Execution time

Process isolation multiplies your test run time, because *for each single test*, a new PHP instance is started, the bootstrap is executed etc.

To amend this situation, you may choose to run full test cases in a separate process (`@runTestsInSeparateProcesses`), or only single ones that are known to fatal out sometimes (`@runInSeparateProcess`).

Comment: Be awre though it does considerably increase test execution. Went from 4 seconds to 90 seconds here with just 150 tests on a small app.

Comment: You can i.e. disable "backup globals" to get better test speeds. It also depends on the speed of your bootstrap file.

Comment: --process-isolation can cause huge brains damage when I'll try run 7000+ tests, I used `register_shutdown_function()` in --bootstrap and  --printer for TeamCity integration. I'll share sources later this month.

Answer (score 2):

set_error_handler() won't help you there. You can catch fatal errors using [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

Comment: As said, I'd like to have a PHPUnit error (I want the phpunit output not to be messed up). I've extended the description of the question.