# PHPunit won't display syntax errors - how to fix

Tags: error-handling, phpunit, error-logging

In my code, not the test, but the actuall class I am testing there is an `if{` no closing `}`
PHPunit just crashes without telling what went wrong.
How do I configure it to show me the errors that it encounters?

the class is

```
class A{

public function __construct(){
if(true){

}

}
```

and the test is

```
$A=new A;
```

Comment: can you provide your code and the test code?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841190/phpunit-fatal-error-handling.

Comment: Similar but not. If I understand it, that ticket shows how u can catch fatal errors through an external process (eclipse plugin in this case) My problem is I see no output. At least, I think my issue is different.

Answer (score 0):

Its very common to run lint (php -l [filename.php]) first, since trying to test code that is intrinsically broken, doesn't seem worthwhile in the first place.